# variant of geom_encircle in lattice package

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

Consider the `df`:

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2),y=c(1,2,2)*100)
```

And the following plot:

```
gg <- ggplot(d,aes(x,y))
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0.5,1))
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.5,1))

gg + geom_encircle(s_shape=1, expand=0) + geom_point()
```

I would like to know whether there is any sort of circling or making an ellipse of a particular part of a graph in the lattice package like ggplot/gggalt has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too hard to put together a `panel.chull()` that superimposes a convex hull on the plot. The `layer()` function from `latticeExtra` makes lattice graphics a little bit more ggplot-like ...

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2),y=c(1,2,2)*100)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

panel.chull <- function(x, y, type="l", ...) {
    ch <- grDevices::chull(x, y)
    ch <- c(ch,ch[1]) ## close the polygon
    panel.xyplot(x[ch],y[ch], type=type, ...)
}
```

Now deploy it:

```
g1 <- xyplot(y~x,data=d)  ## base plot
g1 + layer(panel.chull(x,y,col="red"))  ## add convex hull
```

[image]

Notes:

1. it might take a little more work to get it to behave sensibly with a grouping variable
2. if you want the full range of stuff that `geom_encircle` does, you can probably import the guts of that code into your own custom panel function ...

Comment: thanks. Could you perhaps help me out at this case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730927/delimit-sections-in-a-lattice-plot

Comment: I need to get it to behave sensibly with a grouping variable, either shading areas or delimiting it by any geometry-line drawing.